# When I type the name of a character vector in R, how can I print without unnecessary lines?

Tags: r, vector, printing

I am working with some character vector, with the size of each elements ranging from 4 to 855.
Let's assume the name of such vector is y. When I type "y", R prints out the whole vector, and the problem is that each element takes the same number of lines. Thus, if it takes 8 lines to print the elements with 855 character, then R also give 8 lines to the elements with only 4 character, and this way shows a lot of unnecessary lines

I want to remove this unnecessary lines. For example, I want

```
[1] "a"


[2]"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

to be printed as

```
[1] "a"
[2]"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

when I type the name of this vector.

How can I change this setting?

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example? What you ask is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the behavior you describe with extra lines being added to the printed output is not universal. For instance, my R Console on Mac (3.1.2) does not print the extra lines you described, but I get the extra lines when running the exact same version of R on the terminal.

You can do this with `cat`, looping through the vector and constructing the output as you wish:

```
> for (i in seq(y)) cat(paste0("[", i, "] \"", y[i], "\"\n"))
[1] "aaaa"
[2] "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
[3] "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
[4] "aa"
```

Comment: or `message` (better than `cat`): `for (i in seq(y)) message(paste0("[", i, "] \"", y[i]))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
y<-c("aaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aa")
y
```

You will notice that the top 2 lines have gaps underneath them when returned in the console.

The help from `?format` details what is going on:

"Justification for character vectors (and objects converted to character vectors by their methods) is done on display width (see nchar), taking double-width characters and the rendering of special characters (as escape sequences, including escaping backslash but not double quote: see print.default) into account. Thus the width is as displayed by print(quote = FALSE) and not as displayed by cat. Character strings are padded with blanks to the display width of the widest. (If na.encode = FALSE missing character strings are not included in the width computations and are not encoded.)"

I think the solution here is to use `cat` for the printing.

An easy way to see how each element is padded with blank characters is to do the following:

```
format(y, trim=T)
```